# Strange/Severe Socket receive Bug in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a simple program that reads from the socket. Normally it works well. but sometimes The receive is reading 2 bytes that is already read. The structure of the message is 
1 byte header, 3 bytes msgLength, msgLength bytes msg, byte trailer.
I record the traffic with WireShark and it seems fine.

The problem occurs as follows:

```
packet X = ........ endOfPreviousMessage, trailer byte, header byte, first byte of msgLength
packet X+1 = 2 bytes the rest of the msgLength
```

It reads the `msgLength` correctly (the value is 253) The is read the 53 again! and the message. This, of course, are causing problem to the message parser.

the code:

```
Socket CAMListenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
CAMListenSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,CAMListenPort));
CAMListenSocket.Listen(10);

CAMSocket = CAMListenSocket.Accept();


    internal void CAMSocketReceive()
    {
        byte[] hdrBuffer = new byte[4];
        while (Active)
        {
            try
            {
                int read = CAMSocket.Receive(hdrBuffer,4,SocketFlags.None); //Reading the first 4 bytes
                if (read == 0)
                {
                    Logger.Warn(" disconnecting");
                    Active = false;
                    break;
                }
                int msgLength = Utils.BytesToInt(hdrBuffer, 1, 3); //Convert to int, skipping the first byte (which is the SOH)
                if (hdrBuffer[0] != 1)
                {
                    Logger.Warn("CAMSocketReceive::  Out of sync first byte is not SOH !! Handling recovery " );
                    //handleRecovery();
                }
                msgLength = msgLength + 1;//Add the trailer
                byte[] rawMsg = new byte[msgLength]; //Prepare a buffer to hold the CAM msg                                        
                read = 0;
                do
                {
                    read+= CAMSocket.Receive(rawMsg, read, msgLength - read, SocketFlags.None); //Read MSG_LENGTH bytes.                                                                        
                } while (read < msgLength);

                CAMMessage cam = new CAMMessage(rawMsg); //parse the message
                CAMQueue.Add(cam); //Add to the CAM queue
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Error while reading from CAM socket: ", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've got one bug in your code here, to start with:

```
    int read = CAMSocket.Receive(hdrBuffer,4,SocketFlags.None);
    if (read == 0)
    {
        Logger.Warn(" disconnecting");
        Active = false;
        break;
    }
    int msgLength = Utils.BytesToInt(hdrBuffer, 1, 3);
```

What if `read` is 1, 2 or 3? You may not have read all 4 bytes. It's unlikely, but possible. If the message length is the same as for the previous message, you'd see *exactly* the behaviour you're describing. (It would probably be better to use a new byte array for each set of header bytes, then you wouldn't be reusing the "old" data, which could be causing confusion.)

I *very* much doubt that this is a bug in the .NET socket implementation.

For the sake of diagnostics, you could always log the return value of each call to `Read`, and possibly even the data that's been read.

Comment: thanks. 1) you are right about the bug, but it can't explain it because it reads the message length correctly.2) The length of the messages is always the same (253) But i didn't understand why it explains the problem. It reads the length correctly but when i continue to read i am reading th 53 byes again.

Comment: @ofer: But if there are two messages with the same length, that's what you'd see - because you're reusing the header buffer from the previous message.